# Decode URL not working on woocommerce API connection

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, decode

Scenario: Trying to connect one of my shops to an external service using woocmmerce API, when hit approve button to accept connection, the url where it goes is:

```
xxx.com/wc-auth%2Fv1/access_granted/?app_name=xxxx&user_id=f07403abf98405677a5f19f658e9bf&return_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.xxx.com%2Fadd-a-store&callback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.xxx.com%2Fconnect%2Fincoming&scope=read_write&wc_auth_nonce=ff052c27f9
```

Result: Then site throws the following error: "Error: Missing parameter app_name."

Problem: for some reason my woocommerce or wordpress (other sites on same server works just fine doing same steps) are not being able to decode the url and put / instead of %2 and a ? instead of %3F. If you use a decoding tool then it gives you right URL and everything works fine.

I can see this file at this location /public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php, which suposedly has to do the right redirection, but it is clearly not doing so.

Thanks
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I found out this seemed to be a bug on the latest WPML update. Im already on their support forum to report the bug.

Thanks
kind regards